# No room for actionbar overflow menu item for small screen width

Tags: android, xml, menu, menuitem

I have 5 menu items that are set as `app:showAsAction="always"` in the xml besides the overflow menu that show in most devices.However when I tried my app on a phone with a small screen width the overflow menu which is at the far right didn't show up except when rotating the phone horizontally.I can see there is enough space for the Overflow menu.Is there a way to resize the Action bar items depending on the phone width,maybe change theme or is deleting menu items the only way?.

Answer (score 0):

If the screen width doesn't allow for 5 menu items that are `app:showAsAction="always"`, then you need to change your design.  Perhaps mark some of them as `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` which will show them if they fit and put them into the overflow menu if they don't.

From android's documentation for SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS:

*Always show this item as a button in an Action Bar. Use sparingly! If too many items are set to always show in the Action Bar it can crowd the Action Bar and degrade the user experience on devices with smaller screens. A good rule of thumb is to have no more than 2 items set to always show at a time.*

Comment: I have tried `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` however the item shows in the overflow menu for the device that had room for it.

Comment: I found that the best way was just to change the padding of the items in the image asset menu :) .Didn't put this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the official doc, for smaller than 360dp it will fit max 2 items.

> Action buttons in the main action bar may not occupy more than 50% of
>   the bar's width. Action buttons on bottom action bars can use the
>   entire width.
>
> The screen width in density-independent pixels (dp) determine the
>   number of items that will fit in the main action bar:
>
> - smaller than 360 dp = 2 icons
> - 360-499 dp = 3 icons
> - 500-599 dp = 4 icons
> - 600 dp and larger = 5 icons

[image]

[See the official document](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html#ActionButtons)